# Converting location names into country names in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I have a [dataframe](https://www.kaggle.com/gpreda/covid19-tweets/version/24) `df` such that:

```
print(df['user_location'].value_counts())
```

```
India                           3741
United States                   2455
New Delhi, India                1721
Mumbai, India                   1401
Washington, DC                  1354
                                ... 
SpaceCoast,Florida                 1
stuck in a book.                   1
Beirut , Lebanon                   1
Royston Vasey - Tralfamadore       1
Langham, Colchester                1
Name: user_location, Length: 26920, dtype: int64
```

I wanted to know the frequency of specific countries like `USA`, `India` from the `user_location` column. Then I wanted to plot the frequencies as `USA`, `India`, and `Others`.
So, I thought about applying some operation on that column such that the `value_counts()` would give the output as:

```
India     (sum of all frequencies of all the locations in India including cities, states, etc.)
USA       (sum of all frequencies of all the locations in the USA including cities, states, etc.)
Others    (sum of all frequencies of the other locations)
```

It seemed to me that I should merge the frequencies of rows containing the same countries and merge the rest of them together! But the complexity appeared while handling the rows that contain the names of cities, states, etc. instead of their country names.

---

The solution what I have come up with so far is given below (and also in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63711039/7673979)):

Firstly, I have tried to get all the locations including cities, unions, states, districts, territories. Then I have made a function `checkl()` such that it can check if the location is India or USA and then convert it into its country name. Finally the function has been applied on the [dataframe](https://www.kaggle.com/gpreda/covid19-tweets/version/24) column `df['user_location']` :

```
# Trying to get all the locations of USA and India

import pandas as pd

us_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States'
us_states = pd.read_html(us_url)[0].iloc[:, 0].tolist()
us_cities = pd.read_html(us_url)[0].iloc[:, 1].tolist() + pd.read_html(us_url)[0].iloc[:, 2].tolist() + pd.read_html(us_url)[0].iloc[:, 3].tolist()
us_Federal_district = pd.read_html(us_url)[1].iloc[:, 0].tolist()
us_Inhabited_territories = pd.read_html(us_url)[2].iloc[:, 0].tolist()
us_Uninhabited_territories = pd.read_html(us_url)[3].iloc[:, 0].tolist()
us_Disputed_territories = pd.read_html(us_url)[4].iloc[:, 0].tolist()

us = us_states + us_cities + us_Federal_district + us_Inhabited_territories + us_Uninhabited_territories + us_Disputed_territories

in_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_and_union_territories_of_India#States_and_Union_territories'
in_states = pd.read_html(in_url)[3].iloc[:, 0].tolist() + pd.read_html(in_url)[3].iloc[:, 4].tolist() + pd.read_html(in_url)[3].iloc[:, 5].tolist()
in_unions = pd.read_html(in_url)[4].iloc[:, 0].tolist()
ind = in_states + in_unions

usToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in us])
indToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in ind]) 


# Country name checker function

def checkl(T): 
    TSplit_space = [x.lower().strip() for x in T.split()]
    TSplit_comma = [x.lower().strip() for x in T.split(',')]
    TSplit = list(set().union(TSplit_space, TSplit_comma))
    res_ind = [ele for ele in ind if(ele in T)]
    res_us = [ele for ele in us if(ele in T)]
  
    if 'india' in TSplit or 'hindustan' in TSplit or 'bharat' in TSplit or T.lower() in indToStr.lower() or bool(res_ind) == True :
        T = 'India'
    elif 'US' in T or 'USA' in T or 'United States' in T or 'usa' in TSplit or 'united state' in TSplit or T.lower() in usToStr.lower() or bool(res_us) == True:
        T = 'USA'
    elif len(T.split(','))>1 :
        if T.split(',')[0] in indToStr or  T.split(',')[1] in indToStr :
             T = 'India'
        elif T.split(',')[0] in usToStr or  T.split(',')[1] in usToStr :
             T = 'USA'
        else:
             T = "Others"
    else:
        T = "Others"
    return T

# Appling the function on the dataframe column

print(df['user_location'].dropna().apply(checkl).value_counts())
```

```
Others    74206
USA       47840
India     20291
Name: user_location, dtype: int64
```

I am quite new in python coding. I think this code can be written in a better and more compact form. Also, I think there are still a lot of edge cases left to deal with.

Any criticisms and suggestions to improve the efficiency & readability of my code would be greatly appreciated. Also, I want to know if there exist any dedicated python modules so that it can convert all the locations automatically into their country names!

Comment: I'm Pretty sure this would report Indiana and Indianapolis as India belongings.

Comment: Yes, it's one of the issues my code couldn't solve. 
If I  interchange the conditions of `if` and `elif` statements, it would report `India` as USA belongings. 
Can you please suggest me how to improve it?

Comment: I found a way for it though I am not sure about the efficiency. I have updated my code by removing the `'India' in T` from the `if` statement.  Kindly check it now.

Answer (score 2):

**Test cases**

I would create test cases. Something like the code below, but using the `unittest` or `pytest` module would be better. That way you can change the code with more confidence.

```
known_values = [
    ('astroworld', 'Others'),
    ('New York, NY', 'USA'),
    ('Indianapolis, IN', 'USA'),
    ('Pewee Valley, KY', 'USA'),
    ('Stuck in the Middle ', 'Others'),
    ('Jammu and Kashmir', 'India'),
    ('Новоро́ссия', 'Others'),
    ('Gainesville, FL', 'USA'),
    ('Dhaka,Bangladesh', 'Others'),
    ('Hotel living - various cities!  Who needs a home when hotel living is so fabulous!', 'Others'),
    ('Africa', 'Others'),
    ('New Delhi', 'India'),
    ('Nagaland, India', 'India'),
    ('Brussels', 'Others'),
    ('Florida, USA', 'USA'),
    ('Northwest Indiana', 'USA'),
    ('Graz', 'Others'),
    ('Mumbai, India', 'India'),
 ]

for user_loc, loc in known_values:
  print(user_loc)   # The last printed before the assertion error that fails, feel free to comment out
  assert checkl(user_loc) == loc
```

**read_html**

I would use pd.read_html just twice, for the two files, and I would use those dataframes later many times. For example:

```
india_table = pd.read_html(in_url)
in_states = india_table[3].iloc[:, 0].tolist() + india_table[3].iloc[:, 4].tolist() + \
        india_table[3].iloc[:, 5].tolist()
in_unions = india_table[4].iloc[:, 0].tolist()
```

I guess it is faster, because there is no need to fetch and read the web page several times.

**Other**

You might define TSplit like that:

TSplit = T.strip().lower().replace(",", " ").split()

This replaces the commas with spaces first, so you don't need to parse twice. Its result will be different however. I'm not sure which is the best.

For example here are the results for `Talangana Hyderabad, India` and `Minneapolis,MN`:

```
 new TSplit: ['talangana', 'hyderabad', 'india']
old TSplit: ['india', 'hyderabad,', 'talangana hyderabad', 'talangana']
 new TSplit: ['minneapolis', 'mn']
old TSplit: ['minneapolis,mn', 'mn', 'minneapolis']
```

I would change `bool(res_ind) == True` to `len(res_ind) > 0`. It's clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Where should I put your fist code block of test cases in my code? If I put it below my `checkl()` function, it gives me `AssertionError` in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: And also, your suggested modification has reduced the `USA` frequency from `47840` to `47837`! Why is it happening?

Comment: Instead of the assert column, you can use print(checkl(user_loc),  loc, user_loc) and you can see which assertion fails. Assertion error means, that at least in one of the cases my assumption is not true. I've run the code in your question and the tests and it haven't failed, so you might have changed the checkl function. Running the test cases shouldn't alter the results. It is just calls the checkl functions some times, doesn't change the df data frame, so the result of the print in the end should be the same, as the one without testing.

Comment: Yes, `print(checkl(user_loc), loc, user_loc) ` is working okay.

Comment: In previous comment, I meant, your suggested modification (on `TSplit`) is reducing the `USA` frequency from `47840` to `47837`. I don't understand why does it change! 
As I can't properly show a code block in the comment, I am giving a Pastebin link of the modified `checkl` function: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Yvhsr8jrkq/
Please check it.
Another thing, if you have seen my updated question (the output of my test list `P`), my function `checkl` is printing `Others` for some USA locations with lower case. Can you please tell me how to fix that drawback?

Comment: @raf It is easy to find the differences. You can print the cases where the result is different. You create the new version with a different name like checkl2, then
for uloc in df.user_location:
   if chekl(uloc) != checkl2(uloc):
      print(chekl(uloc), checkl2(uloc), uloc)

Comment: While trying to compare between `checkl` and `checkl2` by your suggestion, it gave me: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'`!. Kindly check my [code (Pastebin link)](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tTx8vtg4N5/) and [error (Pastebin link)](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Y4MW69nMNN/).

Comment: Ok. This works like this `if not pd.isna(uloc) and checkl(uloc) != checkl1(uloc):` But I can't find any differences. I use the dataset from here: https://www.kaggle.com/gpreda/covid19-tweets/version/24

Comment: You may wonder what does df.user_location mean. If the column name don't have spaces or spectial characters, we can use it like that instead of df['user_location']. With Jupyter's and Pycharm's autocomplete feature it is easy to type.

Comment: In your original code there was a dropna. We could use ` for uloc in  df.user_location.dropna():` so we don't need to change the condition.

Comment: Your TSplit is different than mine. Here is the comparison for the user locations https://gist.github.com/horvatha/0c20faa86bfb6dd77a48dc44892b2651#file-tsplit-txt-L64.  See for example "Carlsbad, California US" at line 74. The old version has "california us" in the list, and it has "carlsbad," with comma at the end too (you know why, don't you?). You can see Atlanta | St. Louis | Miami at line 64. You would consider to handle vertical lines as well. I would recommend to create a separate function to split the user location. It is easier to test that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112817/discussion-between-arpad-horvath-and-raf).